# PHP class not found, creating XML document from scratch

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to complete an example from php.net (code below) which allows you to create a SDO data graph and save it to an XML string.

```
<?php
/**
 * Create an XML document from scratch
 */
try {
   $xmldas = SDO_DAS_XML::create("letter.xsd");
   try {
       $doc = $xmldas->createDocument();
       $rdo = $doc->getRootDataObject();
       $seq = $rdo->getSequence();
       $seq->insert("April 09, 2005", NULL, 'date');
       $seq->insert("Acme Inc. ", NULL, NULL);
       $seq->insert("United Kingdom. ");
       $seq->insert("Dear", NULL, NULL);
       $seq->insert("Tarun", NULL, "firstName");
       $seq->insert("Nayaraaa", NULL, "lastName");
       $rdo->lastName = "Nayar";
       $seq->insert("Please note that your order number ");
       $seq->insert(12345);
       $seq->insert(" has been dispatched today. Thanks for your business with us.");
       print($xmldas->saveString($doc));
   } catch (SDO_Exception $e) {
       print($e);
   }
} catch (SDO_Exception $e) {
   print("Problem creating an XML document: " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

When I try to run the code I am getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'SDO_DAS_XML' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the SDO package first.

see the [SDO Installation Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.installation.php) for details

Edit: for windows, you'll either need to find an `sdo.dll` for your version of php if someone's already compiled one or build it yourself.

see [Installing a PHP extension on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php)

Comment: I had a look at that but I'm not sure how you go about installing the package on Windows as there only seems to be instructions for Linux.
I downloaded the `SCA_SDO-1.2.4` package from the Pecl site but am not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Unless you can find an appropriate windows `sdo.dll` file on the web for your php version, you'd have to build the dll yourself I'm afraid.

Comment: How would I go about building it? Just in any compiler?

Comment: See my edit, in the comments from the second link there's a link to directions on building with vc2005. I'm not much help with windows all my boxen are some flavour of Linux

Comment: The SDO extension is abandoned since 2008 and there is no way to make it working with modern PHP versions.